# JOOQ : select all table entries where ID not present in other table

Tags: java, sql, jooq

**Question:** How do you create a JOOQ query to `select` all `Subscription` entries `where` `ActiveSubscribers.subscriptionId` not in `Subscriptions` table

```
+-------------------+   +----------------------+
|  Subscriptions    |   |  ActiveSubscribers   |
+-------------------+   +----------------------+
| Id   |    Name    |   | Id   | SubcriptionId |
|-------------------|   |----------------------|
| 1    |  Dogs      |   | 1    |   1           |
| 2    |  Cats      |   | 2    |   2           |
| 3    |  Hamsters  |   +----------------------+
+-------------------+
```

**Expected result:**

```
+-------------------+
| 3    |  Hamsters  |
+-------------------+
```

**What I've tried:**

```
List<Subscription> nonActiveSubscriptions = DSL.using(connection)
.select()
.from(DSL.table("Subscribers"))
.where(DSL.field("Id").notIn(
  DSL.select(DSL.field("ActiveSubscribers.subscriptionId")).from(DSL.table("Subscribers"))
)
.fetch()
.into(Subscription.class);
```

Comment: Your table is called `Subscriptions`, not `Subscribers`. [You would not have run into this problem if you had used code generation](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/), which I strongly recommend!

Answer (score 3):

The from clause of your subselect is wrong. Should be: ActiveSubscribers

```
List<Subscription> nonActiveSubscriptions = DSL.using(connection)
.select()
.from(DSL.table("Subscribers"))
.where(DSL.field("Id").notIn(
  DSL.select(DSL.field("ActiveSubscribers.subscriptionId"))
     .from(DSL.table("ActiveSubscribers"))
)
.fetch()
.into(Subscription.class);
```